# Firefox does not trust Burp Suite's certificates in case of accessing sharepoint online

Tags: certificates, firefox, burp-suite, microsoft-sharepoint-online

I want to investigate requests/responses between firefox and some private mysite.sharepoint.com site which I could access using my microsoft's email and password.

For this I've configured Burp Suite's **Proxy** (and Firefox Proxy settings) to

```
localhost:8085
```

Tried to configure on **Certificates** tab:

- Use a self-signed certificate

[image]

- Generate CA-signed per-host certificates
- Generate a CA-signed certificate with a specific hostname: ***myhostname.sharepoint.com***

[image]

I could get two certificates using `openssl s_client -connect grisha.sharepoint.com:443 -showcerts` command:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft Corporation, CN = *.sharepoint.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = WA, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft Corporation, CN = *.sharepoint.com
   i:C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----


CERTIFICATE 1 CODE HERE


-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
   i:C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----


CERTIFICATE 2 CODE HERE


-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = US, ST = WA, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft Corporation, CN = *.sharepoint.com

issuer=C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT TLS CA 4

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4595 bytes and written 471 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: SESSION ID HERE
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: MY MASTER-KEY HERE
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 36000 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    TLS SESSION TICKET HERE

    Start Time: 1589794543
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Could I somehow tell Burp Suite to use correct certificates in case of access **myhostname.sharepoint.com** site

Adding hsts false option did not help:

[image]

Firefox version: 76.0.1
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

This site uses the `Strict-Transport-Security` Header. This header normally looks something like that:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

The header instructs the browser that for every future request to this site it must use `https` and that it should fail in case there is something wrong with the certificate.

So you probably visited that site without burp before.

The following advice does not work anymore:

> You can disable HSTS checking in firefox (but only do that on a dev
>   machine that you really do not use to access the web normally):
>
> Visit `about:config` and change the setting
>   `security.mixed_content.use_hsts` to false.

Comment: Thank you for replay! This option have not been present on `about:config` page, so I've added it and restarted firefox. But it still shows the same error codes.

Comment: I'm sorry this does not seem to work anymore. I should have checked before...